# raspberry pi fan control pwm intel

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, intel

I really hope you can help me, I am kinda desperate at this moment :D
I am currently trying to control a stock intel fan (intel e97379-001) with a rpi 4 on Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1038-raspi. (The Foxconn fan in https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000055841/processors.html)

The problem is, the fan seems to be only controllable between 2400-2700 rpm. At least changing the duty cycle only changes the rpm in that range. However, intel states the pwm can control between 1000-3700.
I am powering the fan with an external 12v power supply. The ground pin of the fan is connected to pin 6, the pwm to gpio 18, and
the tacho to gpio 24.
My problem is the controlling of the fan in pyhton/c (I tried both). The frequency of pwm is 25khz (the pulse for the tacho is 2).
I basically got the scripts foundations from https://blog.driftking.tw/en/2019/11/Using-Raspberry-Pi-to-Control-a-PWM-Fan-and-Monitor-its-Speed/

I measure the fan speed with the provided script and I could'nt find an error so far:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Pin configuration
TACH = 24       # Fan's tachometer output pin
PULSE = 2       # Noctua fans puts out two pluses per revolution
WAIT_TIME = 1   # [s] Time to wait between each refresh

# Setup GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(TACH, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) # Pull up to 3.3V

# Setup variables
t = time.time()
rpm = 0

# Caculate pulse frequency and RPM
def fell(n):
    global t
    global rpm

    dt = time.time() - t
    if dt < 0.005: return # Reject spuriously short pulses

    freq = 1 / dt
    rpm = (freq / PULSE) * 60
    t = time.time()

# Add event to detect
GPIO.add_event_detect(TACH, GPIO.FALLING, fell)

try:
    while True:
        print "%.f RPM" % rpm
        rpm = 0
        time.sleep(1)   # Detect every second

except KeyboardInterrupt: # trap a CTRL+C keyboard interrupt
    GPIO.cleanup() # resets all GPIO ports used by this function
```

A rudimental python script for reproducing my problem would be:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

p = GPIO.PWM(18, 25) 
p.start(0)
try:
    while 1:
        pass
```

this should set the fan to the lowest possible rpm. In my case, the rpm output is between 2370-2400. I also tried changing PWM from 25 to 25000 if its measured in hz, but it produces the same outputs.

When trying the opposite (i.e., setting the duty cycle to the highest possible, change p.start(0) -> p.start(100)) the rpm output is between 2800-2830.

I do not really understand where the problem is, I think the rpm measure is correct, as I can only hear/see a slight drop in rotation speed when comparing after execution of the scripts.

I hope somebody can help me, as I could not find a solution after hours of research :(

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope to see if the PWM train really matches what you're setting?

Comment: No, unfortunately not at the moment. My brother tested it with a different pi at his workplace (same fan) but got the same results for the fans rpm. He checked the frequency and duty cycle of the pwm output and got the expected results.

Comment: Then perhaps you have a defective fan.  Are you sure it's PWM controlled and not linear voltage controlled?