# Controlling a fan with PWM Motorcontroller

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to control fan speeds on a regular 3-pin fan with a motorcontroller (sabertooth 2x5) on my raspberrypi-4. The issue is that I can only get the fan to slightly twitch instead of having full rotations (like a normal fan).

I have tested with an LED using the same code and I get a response of bright, to even brighter, and back to the original brightness (repeating as the code runs). I have tried playing around with voltage, ranging from 5v to 13v using a DC regulated power supply but the response I get is the same every time.

[Image of motorcontroller diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxDKx.png)

This is my code below:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO            # import RPi.GPIO module  
from time import sleep             # lets us have a delay  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)             # choose BCM or BOARD  
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)           # set GPIO24 as an output
GPIO.setwarnings(False)


try:
    while True:
        GPIO.output(24, 1)         # set GPIO24 to 1/GPIO.HIGH/True  
        sleep(2)                   # wait half a second  
        GPIO.output(24, 0)         # set GPIO24 to 0/GPIO.LOW/False  
        sleep(2)                   # wait half a second  
  
except KeyboardInterrupt:          # trap a CTRL+C keyboard interrupt  
    GPIO.cleanup()                 # resets all GPIO ports used by this prog
```

From my interpretation of what my teacher told me, both M1A and M1B should plug into my fan while S1 plugs into a GPIO pin on my board. This didn't work, so I unplugged M1B and plugged my GPIO24 directly into the fan. This all works with the LED but not with the fan. I've looked around on some other posts here, but none of the code works.
[raspberry pi fan control pwm intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68357292/raspberry-pi-fan-control-pwm-intel)
I tried running this code but I only get a printed RPM of 6000! Nothing spins and it just gives me a ridiculous number for the RPM.

Comment: `sleep(2)` does not sleep for 1/2 second.  It sleeps for 2 seconds.  The typical 3-pin fan is voltage controlled; full speed at 12v, slower speed at 7v.  Your GPIO is providing fixed 5v..  What is the Sabertooth doing?

Comment: that is probably the case with the fan. If i recall only 4-pin fans are pwm controlled so this 3-pin fan wont work. Thank you though.